# Integer.longValue() does throw an Exception if not assigned to Number first

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

```
public Long getId()
{
    Some code ...

    TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(sQuery, Long.class);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

From this code i get a `ClassCastException` from `Integer` to `Long`. I checked `query.getSingleResult();` in the debugger and i conatined the `Integer` 5.

If i change the code to `query.getSingleResult().longValue();` it still does not work. I get the same Exception. But if i use

```
Number tmp = query.getSingleResult();
return tmp.longValue();
```

it works. My Question is **Why doesnt the first solution work?** Surley i can change my query, but i only want to know why the secound works and the first do not.

Feel free to change the title of my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because Integer and Long are not the same?

Comment: at what line is the ClassCastException? Within EclipseLink? So the Long second arg to createQuery is the problem

Comment: No matter what you do afterwards, you should change it to `TypedQuery<Integer>` (if that is what it returns).

Comment: If you want to not care so much about the exact type returned by the query, you could also use `TypedQuery<Number>`. That still gives you access to `longValue()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query actually returns a `Integer` but you pretend that it returns a `Long` by calling `entityManager.createQuery(sQuery, Long.class)`.

Now when you execute

```
query.getSingleResult()
query.getSingleResult().longValue()
```

the compiler inserts a cast to Long because of your generics declaration. Therefore this is actually executed:

```
(Long)query.getSingleResult()
((Long)query.getSingleResult()).longValue()
```

and a `ClassCastException` is thrown because `Integer` is not a `Long`.

When you call

```
Number tmp = query.getSingleResult();
```

it actually performs

```
Number tmp = (Number)query.getSingleResult();
```

and this code succeeds since `Integer` is a `Number`.

So it is not that `longValue()` throws an Exception but the cast that happens before.

Comment: Your answer is not explaining why `query.getSingleResult().longValue();` statement not working. This should work, because Number, Integer, Long all have `longValue` method.

Comment: @rajuGT `query.getSingleResult().longValue()` also compiles to `((Long)query.getSingleResult()).longValue()`

Comment: if it did not, there would not be any `longValue()` method available (Object does not have it). So the compiler needs to insert the cast to the generic type (which you have to correctly specify here, and if you get it wrong, you end up with a class cast error).

Comment: `longValue` casts the `Integer` to `long`

Comment: Thanky you. That perfectly solves my confusion. I thought the cast to `Long` does also happen before the cast to `Number`.

Comment: Do you know why the cast from the generic declaration is inserted where i call the `getSingleResult();` method? I think it makes more sense when the cast is inserted in the return statement of the `getSingleResult();` method, because the method is declated to return a Long.

Comment: @Kai That is how Java implements generics. `TypedQuery<T>.getSingleResult()` promises to return a `T` but when compiled it returns `Object` due to type erasure. Therefore the cast is inserted on the call site.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for `createQuery` says:

> The select list of the query must contain only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by the resultClass argument.

You are therefore getting problems because `Integer` is not assignable to `Long`. However it is interesting to consider why one version throws an exception whereas the other does not.

I will use more familiar classes to explain the difference between using a temp variable of type `Number` and not.

This example throws a `ClassCastException`:

```
 List<Long> list = (List<Long>) (List) Collections.singletonList(5); // Very dodgy.
 list.get(0).longValue();
```

The reason is that generics are just a compile-time feature where invisible casts are inserted if necessary. Really, `list.get(0)` is just an `Object`, and `Object` does not have a method `longValue`. The type of the cast is *not* the least-specific type with that method, but simply `Long`. Therefore the second line becomes

```
((Long) list.get(0)).longValue();
```

and a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

If, on the other hand, you do

```
Number a = list.get(0);
a.longValue();
```

there is no need for an invisible cast to type `Long` because `Number` already has a method `longValue`. This version does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The first way don't work because you used the wrong way to make this cast. The tree of this Class is like this:

[image]

The right way to do this Cast is first cast Integer to Number and then transform to Long  calling longValue() method.

The second way works because you follow the correct steps to cast this two type of numbers.

Take a look to the follow print. The compiler dont like this way of casts. Not just for Long, for BigDecimal too as well as other numbers

[image]